# Fail to import pictures usinfg shotwell

Tags: shotwell

[Error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuUsE.png)

I have used shotwell before importing pictures from olympus tg-5 and it has worked fine up until today when it give the me error as described in the picture.

Any idea why?

Comment: SD Card broken? MTP/UDEV errors? What do the logs say?  (dmesg,journalctl). Look for ioerrors, usb errors etc.  What  happens if you try to read the SD card directly, not from the device? Update your question  (**not** the comments) with those infos.

Comment: I have reinstalled linux since then. But I did a work around by simply "import folder" and then navigating to the camera in file browser and that worked fine. So it has nothing to do with SD-card. but rather a bug importing straight from camera.